# On-click JS doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Below mentioned is my HTML code for the navigation menu:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>About Us</span></a>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Divisions</span></a>
        <nav class="submenu">
            <ul class="submenu-items">
                <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Div 1</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Div 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .nav-link'))
        .forEach(function(el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
        });


    function onClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var el = this.parentNode;
        el.classList.contains('show-submenu') ? hideSubMenu(el) : showSubMenu(el);
    }

    function showSubMenu(el){
        el.classList.add('show-submenu');
        document.addEventListener('click', function onDocClick(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(el.contains(e.target)){
                return;
            }
            document.removeEventListener('click', onDocClick);
            hideSubMenu(el);
        });
    }

    function hideSubMenu(el){
        el.classList.remove('show-submenu');
    }
});
```

And now the on-click action is not working. Somebody please help!! I got this code from some online tutorial. Since I'm new to JavaScript, please correct the code for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Did you load jquery to your page's head tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine, might be the CSS class being incorrect which is causing the issue, can you recheck with the CSS class.

**CSS:**

```
.show-submenu > nav{
   display:block;
}
.submenu{
  display:none;
}
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .nav-link')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
  });


  function onClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = this.parentNode;
    el.classList.contains('show-submenu') ? hideSubMenu(el) : showSubMenu(el);
  }

  function showSubMenu(el) {
    el.classList.add('show-submenu');
    document.addEventListener('click', function onDocClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (el.contains(e.target)) {
        return;
      }
      document.removeEventListener('click', onDocClick);
      hideSubMenu(el);
    });
  }

  function hideSubMenu(el) {
    el.classList.remove('show-submenu');
  }
});
```

```css
.show-submenu > nav {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>Divisions</span></a>
      <nav class="submenu">
        <ul class="submenu-items">
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Div 1</a></li>
          <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Div 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Aysha  Does this answer help you?